# Can I query the current point from a CGContext?

Tags: quartz-2d, cgcontext

Apple's Quartz2d Programming Guide says "Quartz keeps track of the **current point**, which is the last location used for path construction."  Is there some way for me to query what the current point is, given a CGContext reference?

I'm writing methods drawing a chart in segments, and it seems like if the CGContext already knows what the current point is, I shouldn't have to write the logic required to keep track of it separately.  It seems silly to be passing both a CGContext and also the current point coordinates in method calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I get the current point:

```
CGPoint currentPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(context);
NSLog(@"currentPoint: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(currentPoint));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I clearly was not searching for the right thing in the docs.